# In Spring MVC 3 how can you consume the following x-form-urlencoded request body?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Request body is like the following:

```
invoice[id]=111&invoice[billingDatetime]=2012-02-03T21:49:33+00:00&customer[code]=MILTON_WADDAMS&transaction[id]=f5574752-4eb0-11e1-a628-40403c39f8d9&transaction[transactedDatetime]=2012-02-03T21:49:33+00:00&invoice[type]=subscription&transaction[amount]=651.85&transaction[response]=approved&invoice[invoiceNumber]=3524&customer[id]=kui
```

I have the following code to handle the above request but it can not parse request body into the invoice and customer objects. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

```
public ModelAndView postPaymentSuccess(@ModelAttribute("invoice") Invoice invoice,@ModelAttribute("customer) Customer customer,HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    .......}
```

Comment: Need to see more code for Invoice to see how accessors are written and also need to check if you have custom binders.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your form to represent multiple objects, it's often simpler to create a new object to represent the whole form, and have that new object have fields for the other objects. For your case something like this:

```
public class CustomerInvoiceForm {
  private Invoice invoice;
  private Customer customer;
  // getters and setters
  ...
}

public ModelAndView postPaymentSuccess(@ModelAttribute("customerInvoiceForm") CustomerInvoiceForm, ...) {
  ...
}
```

Then you'd be closer to getting Spring to bind the way you want it to. Spring doesn't use square brackets in the request parameter names to indicate nested fields, though, it uses periods/dots. So instead of "invoice[id]" you would have to use "invoice.id".

If you are unable to change the request parameter names, you are going to have to manually bind the request parameters to your objects.